# Merge multiple df in python and keep the same rows only one time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

i am trying to merge multiple dataframes and create a new dataframe containing all the rows from each dataframe but containing only one time the rows that are the same. For example:

The dataframes that i have as input:
[input dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOdi7.png)

The dataframe that i want to have as output:
[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AswkI.png)

Do you know if there is a way to do that? If you could help me, i would be more than thankfull!!

Thanks,
Eleni

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.